# Simply IEnumerable<int> to List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

The following code works fine:

```
cboDay.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToDictionary(x => x, x => x).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
cboDay.ValueMember = "Key";
cboDay.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

But is there a better way to simplify the conversion? (eg. eliminating `ToDictionary`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure you can replace

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToDictionary(x => x, x => x).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
```

with

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x,x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Throws an exception `Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono added `.ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use `Select`:

```
cboDay.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, x))
    .ToList();
```

It's not clear whether you *need* this to be `List<T>`, but doing so guarantees that it's only going to be evaluated once, and may allow some optimizations in whatever you're using.

There's no need to create a `Dictionary` - and indeed, by doing so you're currently not guaranteeing the ordering, whereas the above code will definitely give you 1-31 in order.